# Android app crashes when using these two together - OkHttpStack AND firebase firestore dependency

Tags: android, kotlin

Android app crashes when i run these two things together - OkHttpStack as base stack for new request queue in volley and firebase firestore dependency in gradle (`'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.5'`)

Gives me this error, maybe firebase firestore dependency already includes okhttp dependency that's why this coming or maybe its not, but if this is the case what to be done or how to exclude it? or Otherwise i am not getting what the error is, please suggest a solution.

Dependencies -

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.5'
```

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-21

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Request;ZZZLcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/RouteSelector;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/RetryableSink;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Response;)V in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine' appears in /data/app/packagename-vaVP5bn4ajPlEZQZDBqyVg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes2.dex)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:362)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:312)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:377)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:96)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:123)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)


UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Request;ZZZLcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/RouteSelector;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/RetryableSink;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Response;)V in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine' appears in /data/app/packageName-vaVP5bn4ajPlEZQZDBqyVg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes2.dex)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:362)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:312)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:377)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:96)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:123)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

Comment: Please paste your dependencies too. Looks like it's coming from `squareup/okhttp/` library.

Comment: for firebase - implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.5'
for okhttp implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'

but if i remove okhttp stack as base stack from volley it works, no problem in project

Comment: Please add them to the question and not here as comment. Use edit button.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore depends on old okhttp:2.7.2, not okhttp3. It's even enother package, not just version. So you cant just exclude it from firestore dependencies. The only way I see here - you should switch to old version of okhttp until firestore update its dependencies.

Comment: i have tried many versions - 2.7.2, 3.5.0,3.7.0,3.10.0,3.11.0 - nothing works

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary fix at [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8501)

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
        force 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5'
    }
}
```